# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header when sending an image

Tags: java, sockets

In my server i'm trying to split an image and send it to the clients (here are called resources). The problem is that I get StreamCorruptedException when I read the object.

Server side:

```
Socket resSocket = resourceQueue.get(k).getSocket();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(resSocket.getOutputStream());

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(chunksList.get(i));
byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
fis.read(data);

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(resSocket.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(data);
oos.close();
```

Client side

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream()); // Here i get the error
byte[] buffer = (byte[]) ois.readObject(); 
String path = "c:/JGCF/temp."+"jpg";
System.out.println(path);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
fos.write(buffer);
```

Comment: What is the DataOutputStream for?

Comment: I tried to write a String. Removing it didn't solve the issue

Comment: Most likely something has been written to the socket before it got written to the resource queue.  Can we see the code handling the socket from the time it gets created?